Rewrite rule for page and CPT returns 404
I build a plugin that creates a CPT called "joboffer";
This is the url/slug structure
https://www.example.com/joboffer/post-name
To display all joboffers I create a rewrite rule.

//this function is fired on activating the plugin
function activate_vvbnjo(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^(joboffer)$', 
        'index.php?servepage=$matches[1]', 
        'top'
    );  
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

And a query to serve the right template.
add_action ('init', function() {

    add_filter('query_vars', function($vars){
        $vars[] = 'servepage';     
        return $vars;       
    }, 10, 1);

    function is_joboffer(){
            if(get_query_var('servepage') == 'joboffer'){
            return true;
            }
    }
});


add_action('template_redirect', function(){
    if(is_jobofferk()){
        require(VVBNJO_DIR_PATH.'/required/public/templates/is_joboffer.php');
        exit();
    }
});

If I active the plugin I can visit the page https://www.example.com/joboffer/
But if I visit a single post like https://www.example.com/joboffer/post-name I get a 404 error.
If I remove the rewrite rule and flush the permalinks I can visit the single post on
https://www.example.com/joboffer/post-name
But I get a 404 error if I visit https://www.example.com/joboffer/
How can I combine this so I can visit both
https://www.example.com/joboffer/ and https://www.example.com/joboffer/post-name

I'm not certain why you are manually registering a rewrite rule for a CPT. Part of [registration[(https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) includes the option has_archive which you can just set to true, and that URL should just start working.
